# Trigger UIPanGestureRecognizer before a child UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have the following view hierarchy:

[image: View hierarchy]

A parent view, containing a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

and two sibling views: a `UIScrollView` and a `UIView`. The latter `UIView` could be created by long-pressing on the `UIScrollView`.

After the topmost view has been created, I'd like the user to be able to drag it up or down with the help of the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` immediately, without lifting up a finger.

Therefore, to achieve it, I'd like to route all the pan events from the `UIScrollView` to the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

I'm trying to mimic the standard iOS Calendar's behavior when creating an event.

So far, I've tried implementing `UIPanGestureRecognizerDelegate` with the following methods:

```
      public override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
      }

      public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
      }

      public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        return true
      }
```

Implementing one of those methods, or all of them and returning `true` didn't help.

On the other hand, when I just try to pan the topmost view, the events get recognized (even without configuring the delegate).

As the other solution, I've also tried disabling user interaction in the `UIScrollView`:

`scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled=false`

However, the gesture recognized still doesn't get activated.

**How can I completely disable the `UIScrollView`s gesture recognizer at some point in the app's runtime, routing all the pan gestures to the parent view?**

Comment: Can you just defer the scroll view's gesture with `UIGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: UIGestureRecognizer)`?

Comment: Could you elaborate, how the gesture recognizers should be configured?

Comment: `scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: <parent's panGestureRecognizer>`